# Is "Territorialism" By Academics For Private Sector Funding Official?

Tags: funding

Academics within the same university and/or department are responsible for their own research funding from both public, philanthropic and private sector sources.

But problems sometimes arise if two members of the same department (less frequently two members of the same university but different departments) are "courting" the same company for research funding in the same area of research. It often happens that the first to make contact with the company will complain to their Head of Department about "poaching" by the other member.

I can understand the basis for the complaint if either:

(a) the company concerned is small and has limited funds; or

(b) the research proposal put by the second academic significantly overlaps that of the first.

Yet I cannot personally see anything wrong with a Dr Y approaching Z Corp (who already provides some support to colleague Dr X and may well have a plant in the region of their university) and putting a proposal for support to them (whole- or part-funding) for some project compatible with Z's commercial objectives.

But (from personal and anecdotal evidence) often the Department Heads discourage Dr Ys from doing this - even when the second proposal is distinct and far better than the first.

Can any Department Head elucidate on the reasoning behind this extreme and practically territorial clientelism?

Comment: Please don't add superfluous new tags. It clutters up the place. Not every keyword should be a tag.

Comment: @Buffy  Which new tags do you regard as superfluous ? I thought searchability depended a lot on the specificity of the tags . . .

Comment: You can search for keywords. Tags are for things that are of interest to several users and apply to several questions. Just enter "private", for example in the search field and you will turn up this question. There are maybe a million keywords on this site. Tagging would be useless if all those were tags. [tag:funding] is enough here.

Comment: Tags that can be interpreted many ways and apply to many totally unrelated concepts are useless. Also tags that only make sense for a single question.

Comment: @Buffy Actually it's important to use "private" as well as "funding" here as this territorialism doesn't arise for public or philanthropic funding. Searchers concerned with issues arising with private funding would surely appreciate the "cut-down" achieved when posters applied the "private" tag to their posts when looking into similar posts.

Comment: You are confusing tags with keywords. Private can apply to private industry, private colleges, private communications, and a host of others. It doesn't stand as a tag. Sector is even worse. If you want to find questions about private funding, search "[funding]private" in the search bar.

Comment: @Buffy You are right - I didn't know anything about **keywords** in SE posting. I'd assumed that the tags *were* keywords . . .

Answer (score 1):

Such internal politics are, of course, not unknown. The various profs think that if somebody else gets a contract it means that they don't get it.

Everybody involved seems to be treating this incorrectly. They should be presenting a "unified front." Meaning they should band together thus providing more expertise and more attraction for private contracts. Speaking from the point of view of a private company (which I am in) a university with several researchers in a field is much more attractive than a single researcher. Multiple people mean that, if one of them is busy or has slightly the wrong focus, then the contract can still go to the university. And when we want some more research done we come back to the university and ask around. A cooperating group of researchers gets many more contracts than the same researchers acting by themselves.

So when one prof does "left handed widgets" and the other does "right handed widgets" they can group up and do both. They can trade equipment and journal subscriptions back and forth. They can share funding of post docs and visiting researchers. They can support each other in grant applications to other funding sources. By the time they retire they can have contributed so much to the university they get libraries named after them.

Yet I do see this kind of thing from time to time. Sometimes it is "empire building." A prof may think if he gets the contract he can improve his position in his department, get more of other kinds of funding, attract more researchers in his speciality, etc. Sometimes it is personal hostility. The profs involved may have long histories. Sometimes it is jealousy.  I suspect that sometimes the "system" at the university makes cooperating difficult.

And sometimes it may be antagonism towards the idea of private contracts as such, possibly by people other than the profs directly involved. Department heads or Deans of Science or such may think that private money is suspect for ideological reasons. That can be bothersome.

Comment: Thanks for your view. I am not talking about inter-academic cooperation here, just the capacity of two academics to be supported by the same large (e.g. multinational) company without either excluding the other unfairly. (Not a cuckoo's charter.) Getting cooperation for the sake of research in academia can't be engineered from outside or inside their department. Individualism in perspective is part of the academic psyche and always should be. Relationships only work synergistically where they are congenial and complementary, so people must choose for themselves.